# Android: How do I deal with storing Bookmarks?

Tags: android, listview, storage, bookmarks, data-storage

I am essentially using a listview but am looking at providing a bookmark functionality. I am thinking that I should store the item attributes in a file when bookmarked and retrieve when required to populate a bookmark listview.

I was wondering if there is a de facto standard used in achieving this or do I follow just the "writing into a file" and "reading from a file" when necessary style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of plain files (or XML) you could use a SQLite database (android supports that) to store the bookmarks. You'll find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

When I started playing around with android, I used this [Tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/node/110) to get used to the SQLite-Interface of android. You might find it useful, too.

Comment: I am doing this exact thing for one of my apps.

Comment: Thanks... Just that I heard that the database API is not very strong in the current versions and requires a lot of work so I thought of resorting to a file based storage (which is quite simple using Parcelable). But thanks for pointing me to that tutorial. I will take your advice...