# How do I call a bookmark library in the Android and return a bookmark?

Tags: android, bookmarks

How do I pick out a bookmark that I saved on my Android without using the cursor method? ([Android: How do I deal with storing Bookmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561535/android-how-do-i-deal-with-storing-bookmarks))

Intents? or other ways?

thanks.

Comment: What is "a bookmark that I saved on my Android"?

Comment: I'm hoping to call up a gallery of save bookmarks (URLs) where I can select the bookmark to handle for the next action... pasting as text for example.  Can there be a way lieke images, audio and video?  I handled them using intents and startactivityforresult.

Comment: I'm still looking and looked through the logcat when accessing the browser the bookmark....
I/ActivityManager(   56): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.browser/.CombinedBookmarkHistoryActivity (has extras) }
D/dalvikvm(  254): GC freed 3951 objects / 522160 bytes in 139ms
I/ActivityManager(   56): Displayed activity com.android.browser/.CombinedBookmarkHistoryActivity: 1418 ms (total 1418 ms)

so with that detective work... maybe there is an intent but I still don't know how to handle it properly.  :(

Comment: I think I know but I have no permissions..advice? :(
>>
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/com.android.browse
r.CombinedBookmarkHistoryActivity
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.browser/.Combi
nedBookmarkHistoryActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.in
tent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.CombinedBookmarkHistory
Activity } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires null